# How to find unmatched records from these mysql tables?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am a beginner to php / mysql. I have two tables for store students and fee of every month (Monthly fee system). Here is my mysql table schema please have a look to this image. [image]

```
fee.stuId is student.id
```

What should be the sql query to find students list which not submit fee of given month. Currently I'm using this Query:

```
$query = 'Febuary 2018';

SELECT 
    student.id,student.first_name, student.last_name
    , student.fathers_name, student.curruntClass, student.mobile, student.isRte 
FROM student, fee 
WHERE student.id != fee.stuId AND fee.month !=  '$query';
```

Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Following query will be helpful to you,

```
$query = 'Febuary 2018';

$queryResult = "SELECT student.id,student.first_name, student.last_name, student.fathers_name, student.curruntClass, student.mobile, student.isRte 
                FROM student 
                WHERE  student.id NOT IN ( SELECT stuId FROM fee WHERE  month = '".$query."')";
```

Comment: Returnning all students

Comment: You have to check the month value inside the db as well as value you have given

Comment: I am not a php developer  l can only help you with the query. You have to pass the value properly. Please check it with the updated answer.

Comment: Make sure to properly use double as well single quotes